# Swift: Create Array of UInt8 with defined number of Values

Tags: swift, uint8t

How is it possible to create an `Array` of `UInt8` in Swift?
I've tried this with the following code:

```
var array: [UInt8] = [UInt8]()
```

Now I want to loop through a second `UInt` variable `a` :

```
for var i: Int = 0; i < a.count; i++ {
    array[i] = UInt8(a[i]^b[i])
}
```

But then I get the following error :

> fatal error: Array index out of range

When I put the same bits as `a` -> `[0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01]` in the variable `array` then the loop works fine!

Does anybody know why?

Comment: What is the variable b?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)
in the Swift documentation:

> You can’t use subscript syntax to append a new item to the end of an
>   array.

There are different possible solutions:

Create the array with the required size, as @Fantattitude said:

```
var array = [UInt8](count: a.count, repeatedValue: 0)
for var i = 0; i < a.count; i++ {
    array[i] = UInt8(a[i]^b[i])
}
```

Or start with an empty array and *append* the elements,
as @Christian just answered:

```
var array = [UInt8]()
for var i = 0; i < a.count; i++ {
    array.append(UInt8(a[i]^b[i]))
}
```

The "swifty" way in your case however would be 
a  functional approach with `zip()` and `map()`:

```
// Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.4):
let array = map(zip(a, b), { $0 ^ $1 })
// Swift 2 (Xcode 7):
let array = zip(a, b).map { $0 ^ $1 }
```

`zip(a, b)` returns a sequence of all pairs of array elements
(and stops if the shorter array of both is exhausted). `map()`
then computes the XOR of each pair and returns the results as
an array.

Comment: Really great use of map+zip here. One liners are so beautiful ;)

Comment: How can I achieve this with a 2D Array like this one (Java Code)           byte[][] tmp = new byte[2 * (4 + 1)][4];

Comment: @user3143691: I would suggest that you start a *new question* which includes all relevant information, e.g. how your defined the 2d arrays a, b in Swift.

Comment: I alread have it ;)     var tmp = [[UInt8]](count: size, repeatedValue: [UInt8] (count: 5, repeatedValue: 0x01))

Answer (score 6):

You could use `init(count: Int, repeatedValue: Element)` of `Array` like this :

```
var array = [UInt8](count: 5, repeatedValue: 0x01)
```

To learn more about Array initializers take a look here : http://swiftdoc.org/swift-2/type/Array/

Comment: Swift 3: var array = [Uint8](repeating: 0x01, count: 5)

Comment: @HalR: should be [UInt8] not [Uint8]

Answer (score 2):

You can initialise the array using the
count of your second array so as not to get the index out of range error.

```
var array = [UInt8](count: a.count, repeatedValue: 0x00)
```

or you can use the append method of array in your loop.

```
for var i:Int = 0; i < a.count; i++
{
   array.append( UInt8(a[i]^b[i]) )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Swift 3 onwards is:

```
var array = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 30)
```